# I cann't understand the Name and Value in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I was a RDBMS user but shifted to RTDB. As we have columns in RDBMS and data is viewed in row form. Let's have Table name User and Columns are firstname, Lastname, and username. We insert data in columns James, John, and Jhonathan. How RTDB works with name and values, each user has a specific row in RDBMS but RTDB is a tree structure. Help me I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Realtime Database is a NoSQL database, so trying to project relational concepts to it is not going to work.

That said, if you want to store a list of users in the Realtime Database, that'd typically look something like:

```
{
  "Users": {
    "idOfUser1": {
      "firstname": "James",
      "lastname": "Last Name",
      "username": "James123"
    },
    "idOfUser2": {
      "firstname": "John",
      "lastname": "Another Name",
      "username": "John456"
    },
    "idOfUser3": {
      "firstname": "Jhonathan",
      "lastname": "One more Last Name",
      "username": "Jhonathan789"
    }
  }
}
```

We're duplicating the property names for each user here, but they serve the same purpose as the column names in your SQL database. And the reason we duplicate them is that the database is schemaless, there is no definition that prevents John from having additional properties in the above structure:

```
"idOfUser2": {
  "firstname": "John",
  "lastname": "Another Name",
  "likesSushi": true,
  "username": "John456"
},
```

You **can** enforce a schema, but it's up to you to do so yourself in the server-side security rules of your database. There you can [validate the structure of your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#validaterules).

Learning NoSQL is too big a topic to cover it succinctly here, but I hope this gives you some idea to get started. After this, I recommend reading ;[NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), watching the video-series [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s), and possibly also [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video). This last one is for Firebase's other NoSQL database, but many concepts apply to Realtime Database as well - and Todd is really good at explaining them.